# How to append a static components to a dynamic ones in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-dynamic-components

What I'm trying to achieve is this: I have a `<v-window>` parent component that takes `<v-window-item>` children. The first child loops thru a Vuex getter that returns an object and depending on its content dynamically visualizes cards. However, I have another static component that is like a summary and contains a logout button that I want to append to the last dynamic `<v-window>` generated from the store. Here's how I've set up my code so far:

```html
<v-window v-model="reportPage">
    <v-window-item v-for="card in getSelectedCard" :key="card.id">
    </v-window-item>
</v-window>
```

Can someone give me some pointers on how to achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few ways to achieve such a thing, the one I would use is conditional rendering based on the current index:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    someList: [ "first", "middle", "last" ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ol>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in someList">
      {{ item }}
      <span v-if="index === someList.length - 1">
         - logout button component here
      </span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Of course the content of my `v-if` could be a prop of your `v-window-item`:

```html
<v-window-item v-for="(card, index) in getSelectedCard" :key="card.id" show-logout-button="index === getSelectedCard.length - 1">
```

Or if you have a slot in your `v-window-item`:

```html
<v-window-item v-for="(card, index) in getSelectedCard" :key="card.id">
    <logout-button v-if="index === getSelectedCard.length - 1" />
</v-window-item>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help i will try to implement your solution!

Answer (score 1):

There are [slots](https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) that can help you. You simply need to add a `<slot></slot>` to your child component, then you'll be able to put whatever you like inside your child tag !